# iOS core data IN operator, unable to parse the format string

Tags: ios, sql, core-data

I tried some thread here, but I can't find the solution for my problem.
I am trying to write a NSPredicate like this:

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ IN %@", column, list]];
```

Where the value of the column variable is @"id" and the list contains four number. The id column is a NSNumber column.

I get the following error, and I don't know why:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "id IN (
    8,
    5,
    15,
    22
)
```

The problem is not the @"id" named column (like the type), I tried to changed that and it doesn't work.
How should I properly use the IN operator with core data?

Comment: Quick note : In a format, the property should be noted as "%K", not "%@".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mix `stringWithFormat` and `predicateWithFormat`. And (as already commented above),
use `%K` for key paths:

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K IN %@", column, list];
```